# if my join fails, it seems to fail the linq query in its entirety

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I have the following code:

```
public SiteViewModel SVMGetByID(int siteID)
{
    SiteViewModel siteViewModel = (
        from site in context.Sites
        join address in context.Addresses on site.AddressID equals address.AddressID
        //join city in context.Cities on address.CityID equals city.CityID
        join country in context.Countries on address.CountryID equals country.CountryID // This needs to be a left join I think?
        join state in context.States on address.StateID equals state.StateID // This needs to be a left join I think?
        where site.SiteID == siteID
        select new SiteViewModel
        {
            SiteID = site.SiteID,
            Name = site.Name,

            AddressID = address.AddressID,
            Address1 = address.Address1,
            Address2 = address.Address2,

            City = address.City,

            State = state,
            StateID = state.StateID,

            Country = country,
            CountryID = country.CountryID,

            ZIP = address.ZIP
        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();

    // If address.CityID and address.StateID have a value the siteViewModel is correctly filled,
    // otherwise it is not.
    return siteViewModel;
}
```

**If in my database, my Address table contains null entries for `address.CityID` or `address.StateID`, it returns an empty result... I actually want it to return a result regardless of if the join fails or not (left join? ).**

These 2 columns are ticked with "Allow Nulls"... My Address model also denotes `Nullable<int>`... **Is it the join word that should be something else?**

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to continue"? What happens?

Comment: I think  i'm looking for how to do a left join in linq... OP has been modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group join` for this. Check out [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Example from there:

```
var innerGroupJoinQuery =
from category in categories
join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
select new { CategoryName = category.Name, Products = prodGroup };
```

Comment: Argh I figured it out... but I will also check this out now.

Answer (score 0):

You use into... and then do a from underneath to join it to the original query.

```
       SiteViewModel siteViewModel = (
            from site in context.Sites
            join address in context.Addresses on site.AddressID equals address.AddressID
            join country in context.Countries on address.CountryID equals country.CountryID into joinedCountry
            from country in joinedCountry.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join state in context.States on address.StateID equals state.StateID into joinedState
            from state in joinedState.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where site.SiteID == siteID
            select new SiteViewModel
            {
                SiteID = site.SiteID,
                Name = site.Name,

                AddressID = address.AddressID,
                Address1 = address.Address1,
                Address2 = address.Address2,

                City = address.City,
                //CityID = city.CityID,

                State = state,
                StateID = state.StateID,

                Country = country,
                CountryID = country.CountryID,

                ZIP = address.ZIP
            }
        ).FirstOrDefault();

        return siteViewModel;
```